# Как убрать рамку в input при вводе символов

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как убрать эту рамку как на изображении после клика мыши? Focus border none пробовал

```
input:focus {
background-color:#fff;
border:none; /* НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ */
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сделай так, и больше не будет рамок

```
*, a:focus {

    outline: none !important;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

За эту рамку отвечает свойство `outline`. Отключить его можно указав `outline: none`

Answer (score 0):

Это решение убирает подсветку у любых элементов:

```
/* Remove outline on the forms and links */
:active, :hover, :focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```